# Problem following the Android TabLayout tutorial

Tags: android

Working through the Android [TabLayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) I ran into a problem.

I think the tutorial is incomplete.

When I add

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
```

in the `onCreate` method, I get

```
c_tab_artists cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

I've created the corresponding XML file in the drawable directory but the problem persists.

Does anyone know the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

`ic_tab_artists` is the icon you're supposed to copy to the `drawable` directory. In the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), see step 3.